# PySpark: Finding the value of a column based on max value of three other columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, max, multiple-columns

I am using a dataframe `df` as follows

```
DeviceID       TimeStamp           A      B     C
00234       11-03-2014 05:55      5.6    2.3   3.3
00235       11-03-2014 05:33      2.8    0.9   4.2
00236       11-03-2014 06:15      3.5    0.1   1.3
00234       11-03-2014 07:23      2.5    0.2   3.9
00236       11-03-2014 07:33      2.5    4.5   2.9
```

As we can see from the above sample `df` that for `DeviceID` 00234 the max value among `A`, `B` and `C` is 5.6. Similarly for `DeviceID` 00236 the max value among `A`, `B` and `C` is 4.5.
I want to retrieve the `TimeStamp` value based on the max value for each `DeviceID`. Clearly for `DeviceID` 00234 it is `11-03-2014 05:55`.

While I have not tried any approach, however, will the following approach work?

```py
from pyspark.sql import function as F
max_value = df.groupby('DeviceID').agg(F.greatest('A','B','C').alias('max_value'))
df.withColumn('Max-TimeStamp',where(# please help me in putting the right codes))
```

The resultant `df` should look like as follows

```
DeviceID    Max_Value     Max-TimeStamp
00234          5.6        11-03-2014 05:55
00236          4.5        11-03-2014 07:33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [Window](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) function:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
 
l = [('00234'      , '11-03-2014 05:55',      5.6 ,   2.3 ,  3.3),
     ('00235'      , '11-03-2014 05:33'   ,   2.8,    0.9  , 4.2),
     ('00236'      , '11-03-2014 06:15'  ,    3.5 ,   0.1  , 1.3),
     ('00234'      , '11-03-2014 07:23' ,     2.5  ,  0.2 ,  3.9),
     ('00236'      , '11-03-2014 07:33',      2.5   , 4.5,   2.9)]

columns = ['DeviceID', 'TimeStamp', 'A','B','C']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)

w = Window.partitionBy('DeviceID')

df = df.select('DeviceID', 'TimeStamp', F.greatest('A','B','C').alias('max_value'))

df.withColumn('bla', F.max('max_value').over(w)).where(F.col('max_value') == F.col('bla')).drop('bla').show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+----------------+---------+ 
|DeviceID| TimeStamp      |max_value| 
+--------+----------------+---------+ 
|   00236|11-03-2014 07:33|      4.5| 
|   00234|11-03-2014 05:55|      5.6| 
|   00235|11-03-2014 05:33|      4.2| 
+--------+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. However, I did not see any change after I ran the last line of your solution. So, `df = df.select('DeviceID', 'TimeStamp', F.greatest('A','B','C').alias('max_value'))` actually works as per my need. However, I need to change the name of Column from `TimeStamp` to `Max-TimeStamp` by `df.withColumnRenamed(col("DeviceTimeStamp").alias("Max-TimeStamp"))`

Comment: The last line is the one that groups the DeviceID's and filters the rows for the max value (i.e. that line is responsible why you only get one row for each DeviceID).

Comment: Great, it works fine. Just another similar question; what if I want to see the `max` value of each `A`,`B` and `C` and their corresponding timestamp? Using `groupby` I can see the values only.

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.3+**
[`max_by`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.max_by.html#pyspark.sql.functions.max_by) is available. Be cautious, as it returns only one value. So if you had several equal max values, you would only get 1 corresponding value.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('00234', '11-03-2014 05:55', 5.6, 2.3, 3.3),
     ('00235', '11-03-2014 05:33', 2.8, 0.9, 4.2),
     ('00236', '11-03-2014 06:15', 3.5, 0.1, 1.3),
     ('00234', '11-03-2014 07:23', 2.5, 0.2, 3.9),
     ('00236', '11-03-2014 07:33', 2.5, 4.5, 2.9)],
    ['DeviceID', 'TimeStamp', 'A', 'B', 'C'])

greatest = F.greatest('A', 'B', 'C')
df = df.groupBy('DeviceID').agg(
    F.max_by('TimeStamp', greatest).alias('TimeStamp'),
    F.max(greatest).alias('max_value')
)

df.show()
# +--------+----------------+---------+
# |DeviceID|       TimeStamp|max_value|
# +--------+----------------+---------+
# |   00234|11-03-2014 05:55|      5.6|
# |   00235|11-03-2014 05:33|      4.2|
# |   00236|11-03-2014 07:33|      4.5|
# +--------+----------------+---------+
```