# Why is pyspark not recognising existing columns in the dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dummy data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,3],'b':[1,1,2,2,2,4]}))
```

and I want the most frequent value from column `a`.
I tried to solve it using the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df_agged = df.groupby(F.col('a')).agg(F.count('a'))
df_agged.columns
#['a', 'count(a)']
df_agged.where(F.col('count(a)')==F.max(F.col('count(a)')))
```

I get the error:

```
 Resolved attribute(s) count(a)#472L missing from a#465L,b#466L in operator !Aggregate [a#465L], [a#465L, count(a#465L) AS count(a)#472L, max(count(a)#472L) AS max(count(a)#472L)#477L].;
```

But as I can see that the column exists as I have in the output of `df_agged.columns` above

I think the where clause is getting pushed before the window function and hence the column is not computed. But, in that case, what is the way to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: The error message is misleading but it is not about whether column cannot be found.  It is about you cannot use `max` in `where`.  You need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55768324/2956135

Comment: Any reason why you are not using inbuilt spark df functions?
`df.groupby('a').count().orderBy('count',ascending=False).take(1)`

Comment: @Emma - Will go through the link. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Raid - I happened to use the approach I mentioned in question and the behaviour didn't make sense to me. Definitely, the approach you have mentioned would work. I am still not clear on what is the canonical way to use a filter on an aggregated column. Eg: If I have some aggregation of a particular column and want to filter out the values that are equal to this aggregation. Maybe an alternative way would be to take the abs of the difference and sort and take(1). But I am not sure if all use cases where I need a filter condition that depends on the aggregated column has an alternative solution